# AWS Glue dataframe constructor warning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

When running this method

```
## Read incoming data from Amazon S3
def readFromRawBucket(bucket_name, bucket_prefix, schema_name, table_name):
    return glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
        connection_type = 's3', 
        connection_options = {
            'paths': [f's3://{bucket_name}/{bucket_prefix}/{schema_name}/{table_name}'], 
            'groupFiles': 'none', 
            'recurse': True
        }, 
        format = 'parquet',
        transformation_ctx = table_name
    ).toDF()
```

I am getting following warning

```
/home/glue_user/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:127: UserWarning: DataFrame constructor is internal. Do not directly use it.
  warnings.warn("DataFrame constructor is internal. Do not directly use it.")
```

What's the reason for this and what changes have to be made to remove this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at Spark [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1ff22dde1ead51cbf370be6e48a802daae58b6/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L133-L153) (using version 3.4.1, the latest release as of the time of this post), you see where this warning is triggered:

```py
    def __init__(
        self,
        jdf: JavaObject,
        sql_ctx: Union["SQLContext", "SparkSession"],
    ):
        from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext

        self._sql_ctx: Optional["SQLContext"] = None

        if isinstance(sql_ctx, SQLContext):
            assert not os.environ.get("SPARK_TESTING")  # Sanity check for our internal usage.
            assert isinstance(sql_ctx, SQLContext)
            # We should remove this if-else branch in the future release, and rename
            # sql_ctx to session in the constructor. This is an internal code path but
            # was kept with a warning because it's used intensively by third-party libraries.
            warnings.warn("DataFrame constructor is internal. Do not directly use it.")
            self._sql_ctx = sql_ctx
            session = sql_ctx.sparkSession
        else:
            session = sql_ctx
        self._session: "SparkSession" = session
```

So actually this argument, called `sql_ctx`, has to be a `SparkSession` instead of a `SQLContext`. As you can clearly see from the comments, this is a transition issue. But there is no need to worry, because `session = sql_ctx.sparkSession` creates the necessary `SparkSession` out of your `SQLContext`.

The reason why you're seeing this is because aws-glue is using `glue_ctx` in its [`.toDF`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/blob/f973095b9f2aa784cbcc87681a00da3127125337/awsglue/dynamicframe.py#L129C1-L147C109) method:

```py
    def toDF(self, options = None):
        ...
        return DataFrame(self._jdf.toDF(self.glue_ctx._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(scala_options)), self.glue_ctx)
```

and this `glue_ctx` is a [`GlueContext`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/blob/f973095b9f2aa784cbcc87681a00da3127125337/awsglue/context.py#L52) inherits from Spark's `SQLContext`.

So in the end, if Spark changes its API to only accept `SparkSession` in a dataframe's `__init__` method, glue will have to follow. But right now, that is not yet the case. You won't be able to remove the warning without rewriting that `.toDF` method. But you don't have to worry about this, it'll just be a bit annoying to see those warnings :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is caused by calling `.toDF()`, which transforms the proprietary Glue Dynamic Frame into a regular Spark Data Frame.